# Do I need to pay/add tax on remote work as a sole trader?

Tags: taxes, invoices

I'm a freelance graphic designer and a client asked me for an invoice; I'm not sure how to move forward correctly.

I'm from Italy and the company is from the Netherlands.
They want an invoice and then make a 30% deposit to start and 70% after work has been completed.

I am currently a student with no registered business.

My questions are:

- I need to add sales tax to the invoice?
- I need to pay tax in Italy for this invoice?
- What else do I need to add to my invoice?

Answer (score 1):

I'm from Italy too and I had the chance to work for foreign companies (in Europe).

As far as I know you can't produce a regular invoice to a foreign company in Europe unless you have a VAT ID ("Partita IVA" in Italy).

Anyway, the invoice should be without the 22% of taxes, then the foreign company will pay that in its own country, but that can change depending on special factors.

If you have certain features of age, no employment, etc (I don't know all of them) you can "sell" up to a certain amount of money (maybe around €3000) without paying taxes.

But let me tell you that the rules changes a lot and fast (also depending on age and other factors) so the best thing that you can do is to have an expert advice at an accountant to know exactly what you can do.